# How to convert a DOM element into a Snap.svg element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, snap.svg

Is there a way to convert a DOM element into a Snap.svg element without using a selector? How can I do this?

I cannot find a way in the documentation. (http://snapsvg.io/docs/)

I want to fetch the corresponding Snap.svg element once a Jquery event is triggered, but I have no idea how I can do this in a nice way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply

```
var mySnapElement = Snap( someDomElement );
```